# Thread names with implementing Runnable and extending Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

I know There are two ways a new Thread can be created, by **implementing Runnable interface** and by **extending Thread class**. I wrote a simple program which implements Runnable interface.

```
public class tp implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        tp o1= new tp();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(o1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(o1);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        //(new Thread(new tp())).start();
    }

}
```

It has following output:

```
main
Hello from Thread-0
Hello from Thread-1
```

Then I extend the class.

```
public class tp extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        tp o1= new tp();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(o1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(o1);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        //(new Thread(new tp())).start();
    }

}
```

which produced this output:

```
main
Hello from Thread-1
Hello from Thread-2
```

I couldn't understand why thread names started with Thread-0 when I implemented an Interface and with Thread-1 when I extended a Thread class.

Comment: Note that there is only one way to create a thread and that's to instantiate `Thread` and `start` the instance.

Comment: The two things you describe _implementing `Runnable` interface and by extending `Thread` class_ are ways to define the behavior of the executing thread. Both your code snippets are examples of the first method, _implementing `Runnable`_.  Although you've extended `Thread`, you're using an instance of the subtype only as a `Runnable` as the first argument to `Thread` constructor. To achieve the second method you describe, you'd have to `start` the `tp` instance. `o1.start()`.

Comment: don't rely on the thread number being anything other than unique.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, the `tp` class calls its parent constructor.  Since its parent is `Thread`, the `tp` object in `main`+ gets the first auto-assigned name (`Thread-0`).

You should never rely on the auto-generated name.  If a name is important to you, call the [Thread constructor that allows you to set your own name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.String-).

+Side note: Don't name Classes and variables with the same name as you introduce ambiguity.